# Is it possible to customize meta query in this way?

Tags: meta-query

I have a custom post type called `promotions`.

In each promotions' post meta, I store two fields, `promo_start_date` and `promo_end_date`.

The idea is to only show promotions on the frontend, where the

```
current_date >= promo_start_date AND current_date <= promo_end_date
```

For example, if the promotion has the value of `2022-12-18` in the `promo_start_date` and `2023-01-08` in the `promo_end_date`, it will only show up on the frontend on the `2022-12-18` and then display till the `2023-01-08`.

I was wondering how possible it is to achieve this with meta_query.

```php
$args = [
    'paged' => 1
    'post_type' => 'promotions',
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key' => 'promo_start_date'
            'value' => 'CURRENT_DATE'
            'type' => 'DATE'
            'compare' => '>='
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'promo_end_date'
            'value' => 'CURRENT_DATE'
            'type' => 'DATE'
            'compare' => '<='
        ],
    ],
];
```

I can easily implement this in raw `sql` but unfortunately I am tweaking a filter for a plugin in order to achieve the result that I need.

The filter is coming from the [Search and Filter plugin](https://searchandfilter.com) and its documentation can be found [here](https://searchandfilter.com/documentation/action-filter-reference/)

And here is an example of the code that I am trying to implement

```php
function me_sf_edit_query_args($query_args, $sfid) {
    // if search form has specified ID, change query args
    if ($sfid == 11000) {
        $query_args['meta_query'] = [
            [
                
            ]
        ];
        dd($query_args);
    }

    return $query_args;
}
add_filter('sf_edit_query_args', 'me_sf_edit_query_args', 20, 2);
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean `'relation' => 'and'` property? or are you having issues with the values? You can check it here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters

Comment: @Buttered_Toast No, but I edited the question and added an explanation to help provide more context

Comment: What date format are you passing? I tend to use the full MySQL date time format `Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: Just `Y-m-d`, because that information is coming from `API`

Comment: there are no filters in your question, please include the filter, and note that while `meta_query` might be able to do what you want, there is no guarantee that this is still true when the plugin is involved, and the plugin may have special requirements that need to be handled that require specialised knowledge of the plugin. As a result any answer you get here may be correct but unusable

Comment: @TomJNowell Done